# VS Code QuickFix Menu selected item frame is not visible

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code 1.71.2 (newest). Before update I used `cmd + .` shortcut to open QuickFix Menu, `up` / `down` arrows to navigate on it and `enter` to accept selected item. In 1.71 version Visual Studio Code provided many new things and one of the changes was QuickFixMenu - [1.71 verion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_71.md#new-code-action-control).
After upgrade, I am not able to do this action.
After using `cmd + .` shortcut QuickFix Menu opens, but I cannot use `up` and `down` arrows for navigating. `Enter` shortcut works. It is interesting that `up` and `down` arrows work (it changes the selected item) but I cannot see the selection frame, so it is not possible for me to know what QuickFix Action I am currently selecting. Please take a look at the screen-shot - the frame of the selected item is not visible.

NO SELECTION FRAME
[image: NO SELECTION FRAME]

EXPECTED SELECTION FRAME
[image: EXPECTED SELECTION FRAME]

Interesting fact, this frame is visible when mouse hover on the specific list item.

What steps I did:

1. reinstall of VS Code,
2. removing all my shortcuts from keyblidings.json,
3. In upgrade the `selectNextCodeAction`  was changed, so I checked in DefaultKeyBlidings weather it is correct,

Any ideas why this selection frame in QuickFix Menu is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

It was fixed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160477)

Go to `Preferences: Color Theme` and change it.

Problem occurs only while using `Dark High Contrast`